# load image in a for loop

Tags: c#

```
for (int s = 1; s <= NumComponents;s++ )
{
   fname = @"C:\Users\Johaira\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SpecialProblem1\SpecialProblem1\bin\Debug\" ;
   fname2 = fname + string.Format("{0:00}.png", s);
    Bitmap inputImage = new Bitmap(fname2);

    //do some image processing here...for example thinning
}
```

I am doing image processing in c#. I have this for loop that processes each image from a directory.. the file names of my images are numbers.. but I cannot load them.. what do I do..
It works when it is not in a loop..when I call

```
Bitmap inputImage = new Bitmap(@"C:\Users\Johaira\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SpecialProblem1\SpecialProblem1\bin\Debug\1.png");
```

It is working fine..in one image only..but I want it to be dynamic so what do I do? Pls help me..thank you.

Comment: Doesn't formatting with `{0:00}` pad the filename, so that `1` becomes `01`?

Comment: Well, how exactly does it fail? It's always disappointing to read a question that omits such critical information. What is the value of `fname2` at the point of failure? It should be easy for you to debug this. All you need to do is compare the value of `fname2` with the actual filename. The important lesson for you to learn is not how to fix this code. But how to debug it yourself in the future. You have wonderful debugger tools available. Don't be helpless in the face of such a simple bug.

Comment: You should be using `Path.Combine`. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/fyy7a5kt(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: the value in fname2 is "C:\\Users\\Johaira\\Documents\\Visual Studio 2010\\Projects\\SpecialProblem1\\SpecialProblem1\\bin\\Debug\\01.png" it says that the parameter is not valid

Comment: Thanks. Now it's clear to you what is going wrong. I hope. Now the question suddenly becomes clear and trivial to solve. Please edit the question to include this extra information.

Comment: sorry for a stupid question..i got it..my error is that it should be {0} instead of {0:00} thank you @Lloyd :)..sorry again..thanks for your time answering my question :)..i'm just new here..

Comment: @user2207484 Don't forget to accept what you consider to be the best answer. And I also hope that you take away the general lessons of how to tackle such a problem. That's far more important than the triviality of this particular problem.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your filenames are for example `1.png`, `2.png` etc:

```
for (int s = 1; s <= NumComponents;s++ ) {
    const string fname = @"C:\Users\Johaira\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\SpecialProblem1\SpecialProblem1\bin\Debug\" ;
    var fname2 = Path.Combine(fname,String.Format("{0}.png",s));

    using (Bitmap inputImage = new Bitmap(fname2)) {
        // Process image
    }
}
```

The reason your code didn't work originally was you were using `{0:00}` which would have padded with `0` you loop value.

Answer (score 0):

Your code uses

```
string.Format("{0:00}.png", s)
```

to produce the filename. For an input value of `1` this results in the string `"01"`. That's because your format string explicitly includes a leading zero.

So the problem boils down to your conversion from integer to string. You want a conversion that does not have leading zeros. For example:

```
s.ToString()
```

Or if you want the convenience of converting the number, and adding on the extension in one go, then

```
string.Format("{0}.png", s)
```

The format item has the following syntax:

```
{ index[,alignment][ :formatString] }
```

So, since `{0}` contains just the index, and omits the `formatString`, the default formatting is performed by calling `ToString()` on the object. So, the above call to `string.Format()` is just a convenient way to write:

```
s.ToString() + '.png'
```

---

As a piece of general advice, I suggest you take some time to learn how to get the most out of your debugger. Had you inspected the value of your file name variable you would immediately have seen the erroneous leading zero. You will benefit greatly from learning how to use the debugger to investigate problems with your code.